# Still problems with LLIST *mylist[x]

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

So I have...

> int x; LLIST *mylist[x]; x =10;
> bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);

this does not seem to be a valid solution..

I did add the -std=c99 to my make file, just this alone did not work which is why emil suggested the above approach, because I had originally:

> int x=10;
>
> LLIST *mylist[x] = {NULL};

My make file looks like this:

> CC=gcc CFLAGS=-Wall -g -std=c99
>
> ## LIBS=-lreadline -lm OBJS=llist.o myprogram.o INCLUDES=llist.h
>
> all: $(OBJS)      $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS)
> $(LIBS) -o myprogram
>
> .c.o: $*.h $(INCLUDES)     $(CC)
> $(CFLAGS) -c $*.c
>
> clean:    rm -f *.o myprogram

Comment: not a valid solution to what ?

Comment: When I try

int x=10;

LLIST *mylist[x] = {NULL};

I get an error when I compile 

the solution given compiles but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
int x; 
LLIST *mylist[x];
x = 10;
bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*y);
```

has two problems:

1. You are using x line 2 before giving it a value on line 3.
2. You are using variable y in line 4.

I recommend tow changes.  First combine the definition and initialization of x into a single line.  Second, use `sizeof(VAR)` and rather then recomputing the size based on the type:

```
int x = 10;
LLIST *mylist[x];
bzero(mylist, sizeof(mylist));
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo suppose to be:
bzero(mylist, sizeof(LLIST *)*x);

Comment: Okay.. I think i was able to get it to work... I will give it a try thanks for the help.